# Questions about current

Tags: electrostatics

First Kirchoff's law:

At any node (junction) in an electrical circuit, the sum of currents flowing into that node is equal to the sum of currents flowing out of that node

$I(\partial V)=0$

Than we have charge conservation law:

$I(\partial V)=-\dot{Q}(V)$

Why is in one case 0 and in one $-\dot{Q}(V)$?

What happens when $I(\partial V)=0$ if we know that by law of conservation of electric charges $I(\partial V)=-\dot{Q}(V)?$

In phyisical Experiments $\dot{Q}(V)$  can be zero, but in which case it can't be?

Comment: Your notation is a bit unusual, what exactly do you mean with $\partial V$?

Answer (score 1):

[Kirchhoff's first law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_circuit_laws) states that the algebraic **sum** of currents in a network of conductors meeting at a point is zero

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {I}_k = 0$$

where the current $I_k$ is taken with positive sign if flowing towards the node and negative otherwise.

The current is defined as

$$ I=\frac{dQ}{dt}=\dot{Q} $$

So the [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation)

$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} =0$$

integrated gives exactly the Kirchhoff's first law, so they are not in contradiction.